# Edit nested values by relational _id in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Hello I have relational `_id`s in an array. The object content is in other collection. I can only view `Object("_id")` in my array.

I want to edit object of those `_ids`.  How can I edit by using relational `_ids` ??

I have data response like this

```
{
"admins": {
            "users": [
                "5d089739d8aae228d7f10c1e" //<------ edit this id object
            ],
            "email": "jertacomlu@desoz.com",
            "password": "$2a$10$C/DsmoHK57vIUt7g4wRsYulHLigmc1wGLObwu2/qkFkSeYp28bAOy",
        },
"_id": "5d089264d8aae228d7f10c1d",
"companyName":"Company 1",
"__v": 0
}
```

So this id is stored in other collection name `Userr`.

the object is like this:-

```
[  {
     "_id": "5d089739d8aae228d7f10c1e",
     "email": "jertacomlu@desoz.com",
     "password": "$2a$10$0Slx3yFeb7UD0qep.TWSI.JpQGl0CzlGhNJ162JtA5Uvt6osyrIl.",
     "firstName": "Sima",
     "lastName": "Cezo",
     "phoneNumber": "8877123456",
      "__v": 0
    }
 ]
```

*I want to edit these fields. How can I do by using relation `_id` ?*

**EDIT:-**

**my parent controller**

```
var admin = new Admin();
    admin.companyName = req.body.companyName;
    admin.admins = {
                    email : req.body.email,
                    password: req.body.password, 
                    role : "admin",
                    verified :"false",
                    active: "OFF",
                    users : []
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 admin.find({id:"5d089264d8aae228d7f10c1d"}).populate("users").then(data=>{

        //update the fields which you would find in the data object

          data.save()
        //your data would be changed.   
    })
```

Comment: So , do the changes will reflect on the child collection from where the data is populating ? I have added in my edit how will approach in the users ?

Comment: yes the changes will be reflected,Just console the data which you get in the then block and find your way to the things you have to edit in the user.then save it using data.save()

Comment: if this helped you can make this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a method at model **User** , example to edit **email** :

```
User.edit=async function (id,newEmail){
let user = await User.findOne({_id:id}).exec();
user.email=newEmail;
await user.save();
}
```

In **Admin** ,

```
...
let admin = await Admin.findOne({_id:id}).exec();
await User.edit(admin.users[0])
...
```

Comment: Sorry , didn't get it. Like in array I got ObjectId. Isn't there any way to populate and edit on same model?